# Jasmine test cases getting disconnected while executing test cases

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jenkins-pipeline, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am running more than 2000 test cases using karma in the chrome browser, it gets disconnected after executing 1200 test cases. Does anyone face this issue and let me know any fix to resolve this issue?
My karma config:

```js
config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',

        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine-ajax', 'jasmine', 'requirejs'],

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            "test-main.js",
            // Add dependent package's script files here              
        ],

        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
            
        ],

        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {},

        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['dots', 'html'],

        // the default html configuration 
        htmlReporter: {
            outputFile: "test-report/units.html",
            pageTitle: "Unit Tests",
            subPageTitle: "Asampleprojectdescription"
        },

        // web server port
        port: 9876,

        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,

        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,

        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadless', 'Chrome'],

        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false,

        // Concurrency level
        // how many browser should be started simultaneous
        concurrency: Infinity
    })
```

Package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.28",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.9",
    "@types/jasmine-ajax": "^3.1.27",
    "@types/requirejs": "^2.1.26"
  }
```

Error:

> [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 104.0.5112 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1336 of 1422
> (4 FAILED) (0 secs / 0 secs) [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 104.0.5112 (Linux
> 0.0.0): Executed 1337 of 1422 (4 FAILED) (0 secs / 0 secs) [33m11 08 2022 06:19:12.259:WARN [HeadlessChrome 104.0.5112 (Linux 0.0.0)]:
> [39mDisconnected (1 times) [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 104.0.5112 (Linux
> 0.0.0): Executed 1337 of 1422 (4 FAILED) DISCONNECTED (6 mins 7.609 secs / 0 secs)